# Reading Data from excel sheets in Katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

How to read data from excel sheets(sheet 1,sheet 2...etc) in Katalon Studio.
I am able reading the data from one sheet.But I am facing the difficulty with multiple sheets.

Comment: can you post your error message what you faced

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what the problem you face is, here are my first suggestions to check:

1. You do have to *create different Test Data files for each sheet* in your file that you want to use. [Two Test Data files for the same spreadsheet file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joQZD.png)
2. In your new Test Data inside Katalon, just select your file and then you can select the different sheet. [Sheet selection options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1unyo.png)
3. If you can't see a sheet in the drop down on your Test Data page (perhaps you just added it to the spreadsheet) refresh your project, or at the very least refresh the Test Data. (ctrl-F5 to refresh the entire project, highlight the Test Object and then right-click and select or hit F5 to refresh the Test Data)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch excel sheets from Katalon, at least natively. Maybe with some custom programming.